# How to calculate the emf with flux density given instead of flux

Tags: magnetic-flux, emf

So I have the following question

What is the emf in a  coil of 2000 turns and c-s area 10cm2 when a flux density of 0.4T density in it is reversed, i.e.  in a time of 20ms. Also what would be the the direction of the induced emf.

What I have so far is

.4 x 10
= 4w (flux)

then -2000x (.4/20x10-3)

Would this be correct?

Comment: read about Lenz Law. Read  your book, and find an example.

Comment: I get 40 volts, what do you get?

Comment: what will be the direction of the emf?

Comment: also i get - 40 volts @Andyaka

Comment: We're good then. Given that you didn't define the coil relative to the flux polarity and neither did you state which terminal was to be regarded as the reference terminal, you can't objectively specify direction of emf. All you have is emf = \$N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$.

Comment: Actually, thinking about this a bit more, if the flux is reversed then the flux change is 0.8 T hence the induced voltage is 80 volts and not 40 volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A cross sectional coil area of 10 square cm is 0.001 square metres.
2. A flux reversal from +0.4 T to -0.4 T is a change of 0.8 T
3. This means that \$\frac{d\Phi}{dT}\$ = 0.001 x 0.8/0.02 = 0.04 webers per second
4. The induced voltage is 2000 x 0.04 volts = 80 volts.

Given what you have put in your question there is no way of saying whether the voltage is negative or positive.